How to get CPU temp in MSI Afterburner without hwinfo?
I just got a new laptop (HP Victus) with a Ryzen 7 8845HS CPU. It seems that MSI Afterburner has trouble picking up AMD CPU temps and the solution is to use HWInfo to provide the data. However, latest HWInfo requires you to have a pro license to turn on Shared Memory (otherwise MSI Afterburner can't read the values from HWInfo), and I'd prefer to avoid paying for such a simple use case on a single device. And reverting to an older version of HWInfo (I tried 6.4.2, the latest version before shared memory was locked behind a license) doesn't work for me as 6.4.2 doesn't pick up my CPU temp (I'm guessing some incompatibility with the older software and my newer CPU). Is there any other way to get CPU temp to show up in MSI afterburner, so that I can get the values in the in-game overlay?
Alternatively, is there other software that will show me CPU/GPU temps + FPS via in-game overlay and ideally also in the system tray?
